# jQuery Datepicker not accepting the given date

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a few inputs where the user selects a date using the jQuery Datepicker however it is not accepting the dates in the format I specified.

I initialise the datepicker like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('input[data-initdate="1"]').datepicker({
                [...]
                dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
                [...]
            });
});
```

My project is a ASP.NET core application. When I debug the application in VS it will accept dates like 18.02.2018 however as soon as I run the same app on a remote server and visit the page with the same client as before it wont accept that. Dates like 01.01.2018 are still accepted which leads me to the conclusion that for whatever reason day and month are getting switched.

Watching the network tab there is no request send so the problem must be somewhere on the client side part.

I also added a bit of logging to the custom model binder I have in use for DateTimes. Sending a DateTime where you can replace day and month without running into an error is no problem:

```
2018/03/21 10:56:51.914:|Info| Attempted Value: 01.03.2018
Raw Value: System.String[]
Culture of ValueProviderResult: de-DE
de-DE ShortDatePattern: dd.MM.yyyy
```

Sending another date (18.02.2018 for example) will like mentioned before not even send out a request and thus the model binder isnt executed.

Does anyone has any idea what is happening here?
Using jQuery 2.1.3, ASP.NET Core, Browsers: Chrome, Firefox, IE (all on
the same machine)

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Interesting issue! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afterall jquery.validate used inside my asp.net Project caused the problem. 
Not the best solution but I just disabled the client side checking of the date:

```
jQuery.validator.methods["date"] = function (value, element) { return true; }
```